# Suggested reading for classical field theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, field-theory, classical-field-theory

I am reading a marvelous book *Classical Field Theory* by E Soper, but it is mathematically too compact and sometimes I am unable to follow the equations. Can anyone suggest a side book for solution of my problem regarding reading the book? I also have *Classical Theory of Fields* by Landau but its content and way of expression is not relevant with my book.
The question which you people are saying is a possible duplicate of was asked by myself and in that question I tried to find a good book on Classical Field Theory.But here I need help to read a particular book on the same subject. So in this way I am trying to justify my attempt as to make it a new question.

Comment: I find it aggravatingly humorous that they linked you to the massive book recommendations repository, which only links to your earlier question under the classical field theory section

Comment: And while I think the question is valid, it is still a duplicate question of what you previously asked. You want a recommendation of good books, preferably ones to supplement the one already given. If you can tell me how any answer given here would not be a viable answer to your previous question, I will vote to reopen this as not a duplicate

Comment: Otherwise, consider offering a bounty or simply requesting further recommendations using your older question

Comment: @Jim this question actually has two perspectives of view.First view is that in the previous question I was asking a good book on the very subject and now somehow I am again on the same line.There is another angle of view to see this question as in the previous version I was intended for a book on classical field theory but here the book am asking can even belong to a mathematics book because difficulty is now related to somehow to mathematics.So here a good suggestion can even be a Mathematics book solely.

Comment: Consider making that distinction apparent in the question